# iSCSI SAN Solution for Backup

Tags: iscsi

We're looking for a lower-cost iSCSI SAN to use as disk storage for our system backups. We currently have an EqualLogic PS100 array in place that we use for our ESX storage (with a Ps6000E on the way to expand). We love the device, but it's cost is far to high justify getting another to use as backup storage.

Ideally, we want a device that's appliance based (no Windows to keep up to date), minimum of 2 1gE ports, at least 16TB of storage in a RAID-5 config. An empty chassis that we can put our own discs (2TB probably) in would be ideal. For redundancy, dual-controllers would be nice, but not necessary so long as there's reasonable service terms.

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

(PS. This is only part of our solution. We'll also be off-loading to tape, so no worries there).

edit: So w found [a solution](http://store.micronet.com/MaxNAS8R16.aspx) that looks like it could fit the bill perfectly today. Has anyone used any of their products before? Looking for reviews of these units isn't turning anything up, but it doesn't look like they've been out for even a month yet.

Comment: Yep pushing into the realm of 10TB and beyond is very dangerous territory for RAID 5, it fails pretty often - as demonstrated by this recent question http://serverfault.com/questions/104298/recovering-from-fwo-failed-drives-in-a-six-drive-raid-5-array

Answer (score 2):

Grab a 2U server with 8 hot-swap bays, and set it up with Openfiler. You may need to check your compatibilities as you'll likely want to setup an HBA in your server. A decent Adaptec RAID card is what I would recommend, with BBU, of course. It's a bit more dyi, and you'll need to accustom yourself with Openfiler, but it will be dirt cheap.

> (PS. This is only part of our solution. We'll also be off-loading to tape, so no worries there).

Backing up to tapes as well is nice, but are you planning to keep both this new server and the the tapes in the same building? If so, try to find the problem.

Comment: Tapes are going off site. Nice try though.

Answer (score 2):

You could also look at some lower cost type solutions like Jetstor arrays or Infrotrend they are reliable and easy to work with.